# entity framework composite key not allowing duplicate data

Tags: entity-framework, composite-key

I am using entity framework code first to design a SQL database and "SEED" method to populate the database with initial data. Following are two models with one to many relationship. "Foo" can have many "FooSection"

```
public class Foo {
   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public int FooId {get; set;}
   // Some more properties.
   // Navigation collection
   public virtual ICollection<FooSection> fooSections {get; set;}
}

public class FooSection {
   // Has composite key
   [ForeignKey("foo"), Column(Order=1)]
   public int FooId {get; set;}       
   [Key, Column(Order=2)]
   public string SectionName {get; set;}
   // Some more properties
   // Navigation property
   public virtual Foo foo {get; set;}
}
```

Say first instance of "Foo" with FooId = 1, has 2 "FooSection" and second instance of "Foo" with FooId = 2, has 1 "FooSection". So my seed method looks like this -

```
 protected override void Seed(PDI.Cloud.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
 {
    // First add data for "Foo"
    var FooList = new List<Foo>();
    if(!(context.Foos.Any()))
    {
        // First instance of Foo
        FooList.Add( 
           new Foo{
             // Assign values to properties here
           }
        );
        // Second instance of Foo
        FooList.Add( 
           new Foo{
             // Assign values to properties here
           }
        );
       FooList.ForEach(f => context.Foos.AddOrUpdate(f));
       context.SaveChanges();

       // Get info of "FooSection"
       var fooSectList = getFooSectList(context); 
       // Assign "FooSection"s to respective "Foo".
       FooList[0].fooSections.Add(fooSectList[0]); // Section 1 for Foo with id = 1
       FooList[0].fooSections.Add(fooSectList[1]); // Section 2 for Foo with id = 1
       FooList[1].fooSections.Add(fooSectList[2]); // Section 1 for Foo with id = 2
       Context.SaveChanges();
    }
 }

private List<FooSection>getFooSectList(PDI.Cloud.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
       var FooSectList = new List<FooSection>();
       if(!(context.FooSections.Any()))
       {
        // 1st FooSection for Foo with FooId = 1
        FooSectList.Add( 
           new FooSection{
             FooId = 1,
             SectionName = "Sect1"
           }
        );
        // 2nd FooSection for Foo with FooId = 1
        FooSectList.Add( 
           new FooSection{
             FooId = 1,
             SectionName = "Sect2"
           }
        );
        // 1st FooSection for Foo with FooId = 2
        FooSectList.Add( 
           new FooSection{
             FooId = 2,
             SectionName = "Sect1"
           }
        );
       FooSectList.ForEach(f => context.FooSections.AddOrUpdate(f));
       context.SaveChanges();
      }
      return FooSectList;
    }
```

When I try to run the seed method, it gives me SQLException "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint . Cannot insert duplicate key in object. The duplicate key value is (0, Sect1)"

Am I missing something here? Because I think for composite keys as far as combination is unique, I should not get such error.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are expecting `FooSection` to have a composite primary key of `FooId, SectionName`.  However, the way you have it now, your primary key is `SectionName` only.

You'll have to add the `Key` attribute to the `FooId` property to turn it into a composite primary key:

```
[Key, ForeignKey("foo"), Column(Order=1)]
public int FooId {get; set;}
```

Comment: Ahh! the "Key". Yes I was missing that. Thanks sstan.